# Consolidating a datatable into a more readable format: C#, Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a SQL table that is structured as follows:

The difficulty is that each order ID has a different line for different Detail and Type categories:

| ID | Order_ID | Detail | Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 567888 | Refund |  | -100 |
| 13 | 222222 | Charge |  | 250 |
| 14 | 222222 |  | Tax | 10 |
| 15 | 222222 | Fee | Shipping | -20 |
| 15 | 222222 | Fee | Handling | -10 |

I am trying to consolidate this into a new Gridview in Winforms so that every Order_ID is represented on only one line:

| ID | ORDER_ID | Charge | Tax | Fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 222222 | 250 | 10 | -30 |

Here is what I have and I have made progress:

```
using (var context = new Sales_Entities())
{   
     // saleslist contains the entire original table filtered on the Charge
     var saleslist = context.Sales.Where(a => a.Type == "Charge").ToList();                                 
     dataGridView1.DataSource = saleslist;

     // add 2 new columns
     dataGridView1.Columns.Add("_Tax", "Tax");
     dataGridView1.Columns.Add("_Fees", "Fee");

     // new list that has only the tax lines with the order_id
     var taxlist = context.Sales.Where(a => a.Detail == "Tax").ToList();  

     // new list that has only the fee lines with the order_id                              
     var feelist = context.Sales.Where(a => a.Type  == "Fee").ToList();                                       

     // iterating over the datagrid because I am looking up the order_id and 
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
     {
         // search for a tax associated with that order_id so iterate through the taxlist
         foreach (var tax_amount in taxlist)
         {
             // put that tax amount into a new column if the order_Id matches
             if (tax_amount.Order_ID.ToString() == row.Cells[1].Value.ToString())
             {
                 row.Cells[3].Value = tax_amount.Amount.ToString();
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Notice that there are 2 fee lines for the order ID and I am having a hard time summing those 2 (because they apply to the same order ID) and place them in the new Fee column I have created.

**THANK YOU Ricardo: I was also trying to pull an SKU column:**

```
                    from sale in context.Sales
                    group sale by sale.Order_ID into byOrder
                    select new
                    {
                        Order_ID = byOrder.Key,
                        SKU = (from sale in byOrder select sale.SKU.ToString()),
                        Charge = (from sale in byOrder where sale.Payment_Type == "Product charges                                   " select sale.Amount).Sum(),
                        Tax = (from sale in byOrder where sale.Payment_Detail == "Product Tax                                       " select sale.Amount).Sum(),
                        Fee = (from sale in byOrder where sale.Payment_Detail == "FBA Pick & Pack Fee                               " ||
                               sale.Payment_Detail == "Referral Fee on Item Price                        " select sale.Amount).Sum()
                        
                    };

                dataGridView1.DataSource = consolidated.ToList();
```

But that did not work.
Does anyone have a resource that explains LINQ language and c#. There are many I know but any that you found especially helpful. I feel like I am just stumbling through the syntax.

I also tried:

```
SKU = (from sale in byOrder where sale.SKU.ToString() != null select sale.SKU)
```

and

```
SKU = (from sale in byOrder where sale.SKU.ToString() != "" select sale.SKU),
```

It compiles but the column appears and is blank.

**UPDATE: PROBLEM SOLVED**

After some experimentation:

```
from sale in context.Sales
                    group sale by {sale.Order_ID, sale.SKU} into byOrder
                    select new
                    {
                        Order_ID = byOrder.Key.Order_ID
                        SKU = byOrder.Key.SKU
                        Charge = (from sale in byOrder where sale.Payment_Type == "Product charges                                   " select sale.Amount).Sum(),
                        Tax = (from sale in byOrder where sale.Payment_Detail == "Product Tax                                       " select sale.Amount).Sum(),
                        Fee = (from sale in byOrder where sale.Payment_Detail == "FBA Pick & Pack Fee                               " ||
                               sale.Payment_Detail == "Referral Fee on Item Price                        " select sale.Amount).Sum()
                        
                    };

                dataGridView1.DataSource = consolidated.ToList();
```

Comment: Use a GroupBy to get all items with the same OrderId.

Comment: Which EF version? First thing to note: don't use a UI element as a source for data processing, use the raw dat themselves. As said, `GroupBy` is a starting point.

Comment: EF6. I have never uses LINQ before and I am kind of stuck because I used the idiot proff SQL query designer in the past. Thank you Rodrigo..I will try that.

Comment: If you found my answer useful, you can mark it as "Accepted", so it will be easer for future users to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using the [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-5.0) method from Linq.
I prefer the query syntax for this case, so this is how it would look like:

```
var consolidated = 
  from sale in context.Sales
  group sale by sale.Order_ID into byOrder
  select new {
    Order_ID = byOrder.Key,
    Charge = (from sale in byOrder where sale.Detail == "Charge" select sale.Amount).Sum(),
    Tax = (from sale in byOrder where sale.Type == "Tax" select sale.Amount).Sum(),
    Fee = (from sale in byOrder where sale.Detail == "Fee" select sale.Amount).Sum(),
  };

dataGridView1.DataSource = consolidated.ToList();
```

If you need the serial ID column in the grid, you coud do this instead:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = consolidated.Select(
  (sale, id) => new { ID = id, sale.Order_ID, sale.Charge, sale.Tax, sale.Fee }
).ToList();
```